# How do I add a counter to track the months and years in one while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

so I am trying to create a program and I have the program complete for the most part but I am having some trouble with counters. 
-I need to add a counter for months and years that track how long it will take to become a millionaire.
-I have the months counter correct, but I am having trouble trying to figure out the years counter.

Here is my code so far:

```
balance = float(input("Enter initial amount: "))
monthlyContribution = float(input("Enter monthly contribution: "))
interestRate = float(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))
month = 0
year = 0

while balance < 1000000 :
   month = month + 1
   year = year + 1
   interest = interestRate/100
   balance = balance + monthlyContribution + (balance + monthlyContribution) * interest/12
   print(f'Current Balance: ${balance:,.2f}', (f'after {month} months'), (f' or {year} years'))

print(f'Congratulations, you will be a millionaire in {month} months: ${balance:,.2f}')
```

Comment: Your code is incrementing `year` every loop.  How could this be correct?

Comment: I am a beginner coder so I would like to learn... do I need another loop?

Comment: You need to try and execute the code in your head. If you look at what you did, you incremented month and year at the same time.  So you moved 13 months every step.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: This code showed me I have to really get moving on this millionaire thingy xD

Answer (score 1):

After discussion here is final result:

```
balance = float(input("Enter initial amount: "))
monthlyContribution = float(input("Enter monthly contribution: "))
interestRate = float(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))
month = 0
interest = interestRate/100

while balance < 1000000 :
    month = month + 1
    balance +=  monthlyContribution + (balance + monthlyContribution) * interest/12
    if not month % 12:
        year = month//12
        rem = month % 12
        print(f'Current Balance: ${balance:,.2f} after {month} or {year} years' +
              f'and {rem} months')

year = month//12
rem = month % 12

print(f'\nCongratulations, you will be a millionaire in {month} months' +
      f' or {year} years and {rem} months' +
      f'\nCurrent Balance: ${balance:,.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

@vash_the_stampede's answer works. If you wanted to have a whole number of years, you could also increment the counter for year when month is a multiple of 12.

```
if month >= 12 and month % 12 == 0:
    year += 1
```

Comment: we could also use modulus and floor  division, I added to my repsonse

Comment: yeah i like that way the best, instead of having years as decimals.